# Google webmaster tools no mail receiving

Tags: google-search-console, email-notifications

I am using google webmaster tools to check crawl errors, like 404 pages,i have build my site using yii framework,i have initialised webmaster tool by uploading an html file into the site and verified it successfully,when i have looked into the dashboard of webmaster tools i have found 3 errors

```
1-site error
2-crawl errors
```

i have enabled the email notification for reporting errors ,but till this moment i haven't received any ??

I have tried to test the site ,by linking a page to a non existing page ,it is showing a 404 error message on the site ,but is not reporting as a crawl error in webmaster tools

here you can see please go to this page  , clicking on products in main menu will navigate to 404 page

any solution for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this way will give you what you need, because apache will redirect you to index.php (index is found!?) , am I right?

Comment: @tinyByte then how can i do this??can you suggest me with a tutorial??I just left out google webmaster tools as it is not meeting my needs,i am using bing webmaster tools,here is it http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-set-email-alert-preferences-c73a478c

Comment: I thought this was a Yii framework question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should extend [CErrorHandler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CErrorHandler) to meet your requirements,

on 404 either send you an email or save the uri in the database or whatever you need to do

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error#displaying-errors